# Can you help me with cumulative distribution function? Please.

Tags: calculus, statistics, statistical-inference

Hello friends could help me with this problem since reading a bit of statistics appeared but I can not solve it. Your help would help me out of doubts.

Find the distribution function $F$ of the random variable $X$ if its density is
$$
f (x) =
\begin{cases}
x + 1, & -1 \le x \le 0\\
1 - x, &  0 \le x \le 1
\end{cases}
$$
Also, find the mean and variance of the continuous random variable $X$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

$$F_X(x)=\int_{-\infty}^x f_X(t)\; dt$$
You will have to compute this piecewise since $f_X$ is given piecewise.

Do you know the definition of the mean and variance?